# How to display hostname in EJS (and under webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs

I working under a webpack solution and using EJS to render my pages and i want to display the hostname (my-domain.com) in the render by the EJS file and avoid to inject from a all_script.js like file

I've tried things like this and that's actually not worked :

```
<%= window.location.hostname %>
```

The expected result would be *"my-domain.com"*

Comment: does the unformatted version of print work? `<%- window.location.hostname %>`

Comment: @GrafiCode, Hello, it returns me "ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: _ is not defined"

Comment: `_` as in underscore?

Comment: As you said you're using webpack, does that mean your ejs code is compiled at build time? In that case `window` will not be available.

Comment: @GrafiCode, yes but like vatz88 said, it's probably because webpack compile before the DOM generation

Comment: @PedroZorus got it, thanks for clearifying

Comment: @PedroZorus It's at the build time, `window` will be available at run time. But to say anything more, I'll need to know how you're using `ejs` and how's it configured with webpack.

Comment: @vatz88 it's a simple rule :             {
                test: /\.ejs$/,
                use: [
                    'ejs-loader'
                ]
            }

Comment: Then it means it's transpiled at the build time. You can not use `window` since it won't be available.

Comment: Is that a way to launch it after transpilling like when we launch a `new Date()` function which works great in ejs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an alternative solution :

If we think about it: the only result we can get is a local hostname. So if we really need to get to future hostname, we are going topass it like a parameter by the webpack config.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127401/12084219

*In the case in the previous link replace the JSON by a simple string containing the URL.*