# How to get JSON content in EJS file [WEBPACK]

Tags: webpack, ejs, webpack-file-loader

I want to **get values** from an external **JSON** file and use these values **in my EJS file** which is compiled as HTML by webpack.

*My JSON & EJS working properly.*

I trying things like that in my EJS :

```
<%=
require('./components/products.json')
%>
```

But the only output (in a HTML file) i get at the render is :

```
"components/products.json"
```

I've tried to use Fetch but at bundle time Webpack don't recognize it. And also tried to pass it in a variable but same result.

The objective is to **display** images's **URL contained** in the JSON **to require** them as image's **src** in the EJS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i've find a proper solution. For future people who will come here :

*Everything happens in `webpack.config.js`*

---

## Setting-Up :

1) In a first time i require my JSON file :

`const productsJson = require('.src/components/products.json')`

2) Then i add the following code in my plugins array :

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.ejs',
    templateParameters: {
        'myJSON': productsJSON
    }
})
```

3) Finally, In the `index.ejs` isn't needed to require the file, it's already loaded by the `webpack.config.js`. To display the JSON content, you simply need to do the following line :

`<%= myJson.anything_In_My_Json %>`